# SpeedTest Implementation

Tags: download, speed-test

I'm trying to understand the best way to develop a speed test.  I developed a servlet which downloads a file and deployed it to a server.  I can go to my browser, access the servlet and download a 10MB file in about 10 seconds which gives me a download speed of 8 Mbps.  However when I use various speed test sites such as SpeedTest.net, it's giving me a download speed of over 60 Mbps.  Now I realize the implementations are different and I don't expect these two download speeds to match.  However I don't understand why they are off by almost a whole order of magnitude.  So I have two questions here.

Can someone explain not why the speeds are a little different but why the almost order of magnitude difference?

Also if downloading a file from a servlet won't even get me close, what implementation would be better?